# Pegar o valor de um radio button

Tags: angular, radiobutton

Boa noite, estou encontrando dificuldades para trabalhar com os radio buttons do meu formulário no angular. Eu preciso pegar os valores dos meus radio buttons, porém nenhuma solução encontrada aqui funciona, nem com jquery nem com javascripty puro.
Segue o código:

```
<mat-radio-group class="posicao" name="G>
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G1" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G2" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G3 value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem algumas aspas abertas. Além disso, use todos os radios com o mesmo nome.

```
<mat-radio-group class="posicao" name="G">
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button class="margem" name="G" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: Eu percebi as aspas abertas, ate editei pra tentar corrigir, mas apesar de eu escrever correto, por algum motivo ta ficando assim, do mesmo jeito que n ta aparecendo a tag de fechamento do mat-radio-group, mas vlww pela correção :)

Comment: Testou usar os radios com o mesmo nome?

Comment: Já sim, meu problema é que eu não consigo acessar a propriedade .value no meu javascript, por algum motivo me retorna um erro, dizendo que a propriedade .value não existe.